# how to make relative import between 2 classes in same directory in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, relative-path

I have the following files in my directory:

```
`directory/
    __init__.py
    GUI.py
    Data.py`
```

file GUI.py looks like this:

```
 import os
 import tkinter as Tk
 from .Data import data

 class GUI(object):
     def __init__(self):
        do things ...
```

file Data.py looks like this:

```
import os

class data(object):
     do things ...

class data2(object):
     do other things ...
```

I tried to run the GUI.py but get the following error for the `from .Data import data`

ERROR: SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

I use the import as it written in the relative import documentation. Why doesnt it work?

Comment: Have you tried `from Data import data`?

Comment: Is the content of your file `Data.py` syntactically correct?

Comment: General note: better use lower case for file names, Camel is used for classes and UPPER is for constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
from Data import data
```